# FileReader to preview images using scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created simple code to upload Images using Ajax and used FileReader to preview the content before uploading..

The image would be previewed based on scrolling action to reduce the loading time ..

But the problem is when I fire the event of scrolling, the Error code will be fired ..
**"TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL is not an object."**

```
$('.loaded-images-content').scroll(function () {

                $('[drawed=None]').each(function () {
                    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                    var bottom_of_window = $('.loaded-images-content').scrollTop() + $('.loaded-images-content').height();

                    if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                        var index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('index');

                        $(this).attr('drawed', 'yes');
                        Draw_Image(index);
                    }
                });
            });


function Draw_Image(index) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var tmpimage = new Image();
        tmpimage.src = reader.result;

        tmpimage.onload = function () {
            var MAX_WIDTH = 120;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 140;

            var tmp_w = tmpimage.width;
            var tmp_h = tmpimage.height;

            if (tmp_w > tmp_h) {
                if (tmp_w > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    tmp_h *= MAX_WIDTH / tmp_w;
                    tmp_w = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (tmp_h > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    tmp_w *= MAX_HEIGHT / tmp_h;
                    tmp_h = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

            canvas.width = tmp_w;
            canvas.height = tmp_h;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tmp_w, tmp_h);


            $('#loaded-image-frame' + index + ' #preview').html(canvas);
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(filesList[index]);
}
```

Comment: What is `filesList` ? Also, you probably dont need a `FileReader` + `canvas`, you can just use an `<img>`with its `src` set to `URL.createObjectURL(yourFile)` which will be a *blob URI*, and `URL.revokeObjectURL(yourBlobURI)` when you don't need it anymore, and since it seems the images are coming from user's input, you can omit loading time (and thus your scrolling thing), it will only consist of the rendering time, there is no fetching.

Comment: filesList is an array containing files from <input> file..
In the past i used <img> with its src but the page of site was very bad at scrolling time becuase of the size of images, so i tried to use canvas !!

Comment: CSS wise, Canvas repaint is just the same as img one so you really don't need a canvas, you may keep your scrolling thing with just changing the display of your imgs instead. And is `filesList` an array you made up, or the one from `input.files`?

Comment: filesList is an array i made up, but what about performance of the page when you preview some image with original size.what about the error  "TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL is not an object."

Comment: If you set correctly the images `width` and `height`things should be fine. Your error means that `filesList` doesn't contain a file at the index you're trying to access (can be verified by `console.log(filesList[index])` before calling `readAsDataURL()`.)

Comment: I'll try your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your error means that filesList doesn't contain a file at the index
>   you're trying to access

That's right thank you..